# java : How to deal with an array of values received in this case?

Tags: java

I am working on a Third Party API where, if one symbol is given we will make the request this way as

```
KIMapi = new KIMapi(symbol);
KIMapi .setType(KIMapi .TIME );
ArrayList list = KIMapi .getData(); 
Iterator itr = list.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext())
{
    system.out.println(itr.next());
    // Process it 
}
```

Now my query is that I may receive an array of Symbols as shown below:

```
String  symbol[] = {"BBW","MAruthi", "S" , "G" };

for (int i = 0;i < symbol.length;i++ )
{
    KIMapi  = new KIMapi (symbol[i]);

    // Do i need to keep all the above code shown above inside this for loop ?
}
```

Any guidance will help.

Comment: Can you post proper code? This doesn't compile.

Comment: As mentioned this is third party API , so u need to have jars for it to compile

Comment: Sure, but you've there some typos which may be misleading in order to understand what problem exactly you have. There's no such class as `Itertaor`, for example.

Comment: I didn't mean that. Lines such as `KIMapi  = new KIMapi (symbol[i]);` wouldn't compile. I can go on creating variables myself but then that will be deviating too much from the question.

Comment: Write a method and pass object of `KIMapi` as argument. Write the code of printing in that method and call that. But make sure that your code compiles before writing the new method.

Comment: @adarshr: while not conform naming conventions (it's indeed bad and misleading to start variable names with uppercase), this is valid if `KIMapi` is *also* the variable name which is already declared before.

Comment: @BalusC I guess you wanted to tell that to the OP. Not me :)

Comment: The answer depends on how the api works. Did you get documentation with the third party code? Also, please don't name your variable exactly the same as the class name. From an outside perspective, I can't tell what is a class method versus a instance method.

Answer (score 0):

The "make a request stuff" is really doing several things:

1. Creating a new KIMapi
2. Setting values on it.
3. Getting a list of data from it (where does that come from?)
4. Printing
5. "process stuff" in your comment.

There's too much going on there.

I'd recommend that you start by encapsulating things into cohesive methods that do one thing well.  Maybe you should wrap that 3rd party API into something that makes more sense (e.g. a constructor that fully initializes a KIMapi, a toString() method that prints it out in a convenient way, methods to "process stuff").

What to do with that loop in the second part is the least of your problems.  You need to get a coherent, cohesive design in place first.